# page break after creating certain charts using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am going to generate several charts, first page should have header and first 8 charts, how can I page break after 8th chart and go to second page which does not have header. Each student have a data record containing several subjects and scores therefore each report has several charts for each subjects.

```
    var counter = 1;
    $.get('/rest/report/' + id, function (data) {
        data.subjects.forEach(function (subject, idx) {
            console.log(idx);
            var container = $('<div class="one-chart"></div>')[0];
            if (counter < 8) {
                $('.charts-container').last().append(container);
                renderOneChart(container, subject.name, subject.scores);
                counter++;
            }

        });

    });
    $('body').append('<div class="page" ></div>');

});
```

Comment: What do you mean by a 'page break'?  Html isn't Word. Maybe `<hr/>`?

Comment: What are you using to break pages? a class maybe? How your html is structured?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be able to target every eighth chart, and then use `page-break-after: always` to ensure a page break.

For instance, if each chart has the `.chart` class, you could do something like this:

```
.chart:nth-child(8n) {
    page-break-after: always;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/402gte3w/).